# How to count special chars in column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get count of special chars in column using Pandas.
But not getting desired output.

**My .txt file is**:

```
str
Aa
Bb
?? ?
###
```

**My Code is** :

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('inn.txt',sep='\t')

def count_special_char(string):
    special_char = 0

    for i in range(len(string)):
        if(string[i].isalpha()):
            continue
        else:
            special_char = special_char + 1

df["new"]=df.apply(count_special_char, axis = 0)
print(df)
```

**And the output is:**

```
    str  new
0    Aa  NaN
1    Bb  NaN
2  ?? ?  NaN
3   ###  NaN
```

**Desired output is**:

```
    str  new
0    Aa  NaN
1    Bb  NaN
2  ?? ?  4
3   ###  3
```

How to go ahead on this ?

Comment: What if the function returns something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in one line like this:

```
df["new"] = df["str"].apply(lambda p: sum( not q.isalpha() for q in p )))
```

If you use apply over a dataframe, you have to access the column you want, and tell [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to go over the rows like this:

```
df["new"] = df.apply(lambda p: sum( not q.isalpha() for q in p["str"] ), axis=1)
```

Comment: i want to replace "." with "", and then count special chars, but when i do >>df["str"]=df["str"].replace('.','',regex=True)  , it vanishes the entire string in output.How to replace a dot (".") with no space ?

Comment: The [method you are using](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) will replace whole values. You have to use the [string replace method from pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html). Also, if you use regex, [the dot ( . ) means any character (almost)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html). However, if you just want to ignore those characters, you could just not count them. Here I made an example of both cases: https://repl.it/repls/DroopySpanishLists

Answer (score 2):

Lets try using `np.where` instead of loops:

```
import string
df['new']=np.where(~df['str'].str.contains('|'.join(list(string.ascii_letters)))
                   ,df['str'].str.len(),np.nan)
print(df)
```

---

```
    str  new
0    Aa  NaN
1    Bb  NaN
2  ?? ?  4.0
3   ###  3.0
```